# Is it possible to disable domain enforced screen saver?

Tags: windows, screensaver, windows-domain

My Win XP laptop has screensaver configuration enforced by a company wide domain settings. It turns on after 15 mins and locks the screen. This is very annoying when I want to watch a movie at home, because I've to move the mouse every 15 minutes to prevent locking the screen. Not even a media player setting to disable the screensaver helps here.

Is it possible to "hack" these settings somehow and turn the screensaver off when I need to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a local user and log on as that, not the domain user.  this should bypass domain policies.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could also try an application that automatically moves the mouse on a set interval. I've never used one, but [here](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=automatic+mouse+mover&aq=f&aqi=g4g-m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=b7b968c575c3858f) is a Google search.